# ¿Cómo creo un proyecto con create-react-app con la versión 17 de React y no la 18?

Tags: reactjs

Estaba intentando crear un nuevo proyecto para seguir un curso, pero al crear el proyecto con `npx create-react-app my_app` se creó todo con la versión de React 18 y sus scripts correspondientes para esa versión.

¿Cómo puedo escoger la versión de React que quiero instalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La versión 18 de react ya es estable y está lista para ser lanzada en producción para nuevos proyectos. Lleva más de un año siendo testeada. No es recomendable utilizar una vieja versión para nuevos proyectos.

No obstante, es posible hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

1. Crea la app de manera usual con `npx create-react-app my_app`.
2. Abre el `package.json` y cambia la versión de `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-scripts` a la versión anterior, o bien a la versión que deseas instalar:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-dom": "17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3"
```

3. Borra el `package-lock.json` y los `node_modules`
4. Ejecuta en `npm install` en la carpeta del proyecto.

En la instalación, verás unos cuantos Warnings de paquetes `deprecated`, pero es totalmente normal dado que estás usando una versión antigua.

Siguiendo estos pasos deberías poder levantar sin problema tu aplicación con react 17. Como referencia checa [create-react-app (specific / older react version)](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/discussions/9917#discussioncomment-803343).

Answer (score 0):

encontre esta opcion, esta en ingles
https://dev.to/ifeanyichima/how-to-downgrade-from-react-18-to-1702-818