# ¿Porque existe diferencia en el Index.js del actual react vs los tutoriales anteriores?

Tags: reactjs, vscode

soy nuevo en read.js,
Actualmente estaba aprendiendo REACT, actualmente veo en los tutoriales en el index.js la siguiente declaracion:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Routes />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

reportWebVitals();

Pero al revisar el index.js desde el Visual Studio Code, tengo lo siguiente:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

    reportWebVitals();
```

¿A que se debe esta diferencia? Corresponde a una versión anterior? y como volver a la versión anterior, ya que todo los tutoriales que actualmente sale, está la codificación del primer código del index.js

Específicamente me refiero a la declaración document.getElementById('root'), si se fijan, el orden de como es declarado es diferente.

Le agradezco su atención, desde ya, gracias.

Comment: No me suena que venga con el componente `<Routes />`, siempre ha venido con `<App />`. En cuando al cambio con `ReactDOM.render`,sigue siendo lo mismo solo que en dos pasos. De cualquier manera ¿En que te afecta la nueva forma de hacerlo en tu app? Esas son líneas que rara vez se tocan, puedes seguir cualquier tutorial sin problemas. De cualquier manera dale un vistazo a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/527024/c).

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez, gracias por responder. Me refiero específicamente me refiero a la declaración document.getElementById('root'), si se fijan, el orden de como es declarado es diferente. Edite la pregunta

Comment: Si danilo, eso es nuevo ahora de react 18. Antes llamabas simplemente una función y le pasabas el componente de tu aplicación y tu elemento del dom. Ahora necesitas crear un elemento root y a partir de ese elemento  indicarle que renderice tu App. Es la nueva forma de hacerlo. De hecho puedes usar lo mismo de antes y funcionara solo que te marcará un warning de deprecated porque ya no es la forma recomendada de hacerlo y va a desaparecer de futuras versiones.

Comment: [Acá](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/5) hay una lectura en inglés que entra en gran detalle del cambio.